# Can I hear sound with two output devices at the same time?

Tags: 12.04, sound, speakers

I want to hear sound with two separate audio output devices at the same time: my headphones and my TV-speakers. Is it possible and how can I do it?

Comment: In Linux everything is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. To do so you can connect your headphones to the front panel audio jack and tv-speakers to the back panel of your PC.

Comment: But how can I configure this? I can only hear with one speaker at the same time. When I change this in the audio settings the other one is automatically turned off.

Comment: On my system (Asus P8H61-M LX2 with FP audio connected to High Definition Audio) with profile "Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output)" it works right from the box. Maybe you have to change settings for your mobo in BIOS setup and/or reconfigure front panel audio connector.